# Reducing points but maintaining attributes from original shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, point

I have a shapefile with points but there are a lot of points and I want to reduce the amount.

I have tried `"Points thinning"` which automatically reduces the amount of points but it loses all the attributes/features/values from the original file (which I want to keep). In the `'Thinned Points'` there are columns: `'Count'`, `'Mean'`, `'Minimum'`, `'Maximum'`, `'StdDE'` which I don't want.

How can I reduce points but maintain the attributes from the original file?

Comment: You can use joinbynearest tool so every point from 'Thinned Points' gets the attribute of the closest point from your original layer. And then delete manually the columns.

Comment: Instead of manually deleting the columns one may try using [`"Drop field(s)"`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html?#drop-field-s) instead

Comment: Are you basically looking to cluster the appearance of the points while still retaining their individual values? Anything that reduces the actual feature count is going to either aggregate values into statistical attributes, or will just entirely drop values out.